# Javascript fetch is invalid name

Tags: javascript, fetch, ethereum

I have here following JS code to fetch the balance of an ethereum address

```
async function getBalance() {
  document.getElementById("whoohoo").innerHTML = address;
  const response = await fetch('https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/v2/' + address + '/balance?chain=bsc', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: ({
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'X-API-Key:': 'api key goes here'
    })
  })
  console.log(await response.json())
}
```

But instead of getting the balance i get following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid name
    at <anonymous>:1:876
    at getBalance ((index):38)
    at HTMLButtonElement.login ((index):33)
```

I assume there is something wrong with the headers but im not quite sure about that.
How cvan i fix this?

I have tried to change it to

```
headers: new Headers({
                    'accept':'application/json',
                    'X-API-Key:':'api key'
                })
```

and than i get

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to construct 'Headers': Invalid name
```

Comment: Could you tell us what browser is used ? If it is old, it may not be compatible with the fetch API https://caniuse.com/?search=fetch

Comment: It's probably the `accept` header. The API will not allow overriding the browser prerogative for many request header fields.

Comment: @letibelim - I thought so too, but it's unlikely `await` works and `fetch` doesn't. browser support is pretty similar.

Comment: Im on chrome and on firefox i get an error saying x-api-key is an invalid header name

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the colon from your header:

```
'X-API-Key:': 'api key goes here'
```

-->

```
'X-API-Key': 'api key goes here'
```

Comment: Ok this works now
const response = await fetch('https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/v2/'+ address + '/balance?chain=bsc', {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: ({
                    'accept':'application/json',
                    'X-API-Key':'api key'
                })

Comment: The error message that you received is not very helpful... Glad that it works now